# What MySQL data type should I use for custom data type in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping, entity

from my reading of the book Hibernate in action, I think the data type in mysql should be VARBINARY for custom data type in Hibernate.

For example, my custom data type class:

```
public class CustomType implements Serializable {
  // blah blah
}
```

and in my Entity class, I use the CustomType value as a property:

```
@Entity
public class EntityName {

   @Type(type = "persistence.CustomType")
   CustomType myData;
}
```

However, when I try save an instance of my entity class, I got an error message telling me that I should use tinyblob type for `myData` property. I wonder what exactly data type in MySQL I should use for custom data type in hibernate.

thanks

Comment: after correcting the field type to VARBINARY in MySQL, my code is working. But I don't understand why the error message suggests I change the field to tinyblob type in MySQL.

Comment: is it right to say that the custom data type stored in MySQL are in its serialized format?